# DarkGPT github Noob Fail - "Error: neither setup.py nor pyproject.toml can be found"

Tags: python, github

Trying to install `DarkGPT` for OSINT for work. Very new to python and github generally.

Figured out how to switch from normal command line to pip command line.
Figured out how to get openAI API secret key and set up the `.env` file (I think correctly...)

But running `pip install DarkGPT/file/path/here -r requirements.txt` yields the

```
error: "neither setup.py nor pyproject.toml can be found"
```

Do I need to modify the requirements.txt file? I tried `pip install setuptools` to get `setup.py` and `pyproject.toml`, which worked just fine. But those files are named slightly differently: `setupcng.py` and `pyprojecttoml`, specifically.

I have no idea what to do to make pip install work for `requirements.txt` in the `DarkGPT` directory. Am I using the wrong version of pip or something?

Trying to follow the directions on DarkGPT github page, but there is a large amount of assumed knowledge that makes some steps impenetrable for new comers.
https://github.com/luijait/DarkGPT

I want to use more Github OSINT tools for work, but really struggling to figure it out #notaprogrammer

Any help appreciated

see above, I was pretty thorough

Comment: "But running pip install DarkGPT/file/path/here -r requirements.txt yields the error" - not sure where you got this command from. Follow the instructions on the github page: `cd` to the `DarkGPT` directory and run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: That command comes from:    Install Dependencies

This project requires certain Python packages to run. Install them by running the following command:

pip install -r requirements.txt using cd fatal: Too many arguments.

usage cd to the DarkGPT directory and run pip install -r requirements.txt yields: fatal: too many arguments

Comment: Yes, but you have some sort of path in there.

Comment: Do I not need to specify file location?

Comment: using cd to DarkGPT directory causes Fatal: too many arguments. So I pulled it another way I think

Comment: That was what you were supposed to do, not a command you can copy and paste. You might benefit from finding a tutorial on using the command line.

Comment: I did specify the correct file path when I used pip install -r requirements.txt. The error says neither setup.py nor pyproject.toml can be found

Comment: All of these errors point that you are doing things incorrectly, but you do not provide enough detail to help you.